# Difference between AWS Elastic Load Balancing and Auto Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been using AWS Elastic Beanstalk for deploying my application in Beta, Staging & Live.
I couldn't make out the difference between Elastic Load Balancing. Is **Load Balancing** for detecting unhealthy instances, & replacing it with Healthy one and Is **Auto scaling** to scale up & down the instances based on the metrics like cpu utilization, network in-out etc.,? Please correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have the scaling half correct Auto-Scaling is about adding new instances to keep up with the load - so when the load reaches a certain level it will spin up new instance to keep up - and spin down instances when no longer needed.

Load balancing is about directing requests to your different instances to try and keep them all working as evenly as possible (rather than 1 handling 80% of the requests and the other 20).